# I want to extract some IP addresses from a text file containing port, protocol and if its open or not

Tags: extract

I have this file containing around 6700 IP addresses and I need them all extracted to a different file. I sadly can't find any solution out here so the file pretty much look like this:

```
open tcp 25565 159.69.73.167 1671466939
open tcp 25565 116.202.48.199 1671466939
open tcp 25565 95.216.24.98 1671466939
open tcp 25565 195.201.117.19 1671466939
```

but its sadly a bit longer than this.

Comment: You didn't provide an operating system or anything else.  I am assuming Linux but assuming doesn't help future users find your answer.

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f4 < input_file` ?

Answer (score 3):

If the format is strict this `awk` script will do the work:

```
awk '{print $4}' input_file >output_file
```